# A doubt about the series solution of Legendre's differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Legendre's differential equation has the form
$$
(1-x^2)y^{\prime\prime}-2xy^{\prime}+\ell(\ell+1)y=0
$$
where $x=0$ is an ordinary point of the equation. Although we expect that both the solutions are of the form $$y(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n,$$ we try a generalized power series of the form i.e., $$y(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^{n+r},$$ we find:  $$\text{if}~ a_0\neq 0, \text{then} ~r(r-1)=0,$$ $$\text{if}~ a_1\neq 0, \text{then} ~r(r+1)=0.$$

It is sufficient to make the choice $a_0\neq 0$ and $a_1=0$, to obtain the two linearly independent solutions corresponding to two different values of $r$.

Can we understand, without solving the other case ($a_0=0$ and $a_1\neq 0$) that it will lead to the same solutions?

Answer (score 1):

This is just an index shift,

$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nx^{n+r}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_{n+1}x^{n+1+r}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \tilde a_nx^{n+\tilde r}
$$
So formally the case $a_0=0$, $a_1\ne 0$ is the same as the case $a_0\ne 0$.

Generally it is assumed that the expansion/parametrization of $y$ starts at the first non-trivial term, thus $a_0\ne 0$.